# How do I make my AFNetworking "responseObject" that I receive a NSDictionary I can parse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, afnetworking, nsdata

I have this call with AFNetworking 1.0 that returns a `responseObject` with the data from the API that I want:

```
[[AFDiffbotClient sharedClient] postPath:@"http://diffbot.com/api/batch" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
```

However, I have no idea how to process `responseObject`.

If I check `[responseObject class]` I get `NSData`.

If I `NSLog(@"%@", responseObject)` I get a bunch of numbers (memory addresses I assume):

> <5b0a7b22 68656164 65727322 3a5b7b22 6e616d65 223a6e75 6c6c2c22 76616c75 65223a22 48545450 2f312e31 20323030 204f4b22 7d2c7b22 6e616d65 223a2244 61746522 2c227661 ...

If I do:

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
```

I get the output that I want! *But*, it's an `NSString`.

If I do:

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", responseDictionary);
```

I get an `NSDictionary`, but it's missing the vast majority of the response (i.e.: I don't get what's included with the `NSString` method).

How should I be processing this object?

Comment: Did you try to use JSON encoding to get the data from php? that is easy to work with.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Show sample string content and the corresponding dictionary content and any error that is returned.

Comment: what are you supposed to receive from your server? JSON data? are you sure your json is valid ? copy/past your nsstring in a json validator that you can find online. If its valid and you're missing some stuff then it gets more complicated otherwise, fix the json

Comment: Did you try different options instead of kNilOptions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how I do it..

```
- (void) requestDataFinish:(NSData *)data withError:(NSError *)networkError
{
    NSDictionary *responseData;
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (data != nil) {
        responseData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                       options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                         error:&error];
    }
...
```

Comment: I want to kiss you on the mouth. (It was the NSJSONReadingMutableContainers that fixed it.)