# unrecognized selector sent to instance AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

My app is crashing at this line here

```
-(void)parseUserJobsJSONData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSArray *jobsData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];    
}
```

I am trying to pass the response object to this method

```
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) { 
                                 if (operation.response.statusCode == 200) {
                                     [self parseUserJobsJSONData:responseObject];
                                 }
```

The error is

```
[__NSCFDictionary bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10952ddb0
2014-06-29 09:21:10.173 myapp[9759:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10952ddb0'
```

I think the issue is the responseObject type isn't in the correct format but I am not sure what it needs to be.

I have tried the answer from this question, [How do I make my AFNetworking "responseObject" that I receive a NSDictionary I can parse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315996/how-do-i-make-my-afnetworking-responseobject-that-i-receive-a-nsdictionary-i-c) but this didn't work.

Comment: have you set a breakpoint in your success block? As far as I know, AFNetworking parses the JSON into a NSDictionary automatically

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought @Daniel. It runs the success block but fails on the parseUserJobsJSONData function.

Comment: Yes, because you already got a parsed NSDictionary. No need to parse it again

Comment: So I can delete the NSJSONSerialization and pass an NSArray into the function?

Comment: Try to debug your `responseObject` and look what you've got. You shouldn't need the NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: The ```responseObject``` is an NSDictionary of my data.

Comment: There you got it!? Just access your values directly. I mean I don't know your JSON structure but it should look like: `responseObject[@"key"]` ...(the dictionary may be needs a cast)